# Command TCL doesn't always work

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I know, I should use the TCL command. But sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. When it works, the console responds Collision -> Off (or On), when it doesn't work, the command returns nothing.

Comment: Did you make sure you weren't putting this command on anuthing?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have nothing selected. If there's a string at the top of your command line interface (e.g. `000E0CDB`), then try clicking anywhere until it's gone. Otherwise it'll turn off clipping for that target.

Source: [Skyrim Console commands](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29#TCL)

Comment: Wow, so simple! This has happened to me, too, although going through a loading screen (which happens to also deselect anything you might have clicked on...) was always my solution. This should make my life so much easier!

Answer (score -1):

This has happened to me, and I will try to relate my experience with the PC game console and the steps I took.

If I use `tgm` and `tcl`, and while collision is `off`, come across an enemy and try and engage said enemy. It will not work for obvious collision detection off reasons.

Then I turn collision `on`, kill the enemy, while `tgm` is in effect, then `tcl` stops working for me.

Then I have to save the entire game and exit to desktop, and restart the game. Then reload the most recent save.

This is in Steam offline mode though which should not matter.

Without speculating on the actual code, it seems to be an issue I think with the console collision on/off mechanism.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think he did it many times which is why there is a down-vote.

Answer (score -1):

You just cant use TCL in certain areas, Like riften for example.

Comment: Why not?  What's different about these areas that disables TCL?